# Bit conversion tool in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bit-manipulation, endianness

Are there any built in utilities or macros in the objective-c libraries for iOS that will allow you to convert bytes to and from integers with respect to endianess?

Please don't tell me to use bit-shifting operations.  I am trying to avoid writing custom code to do this if it already exists.

I would like the code to convert NSData* to primitive types (int, uint, short, etc) and to convert primitive types back to NSData*.

Comment: a squillion choices here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the bytes from `NSData` by accessing the `bytes` property. Then just cast that to a pointer to whatever type you want. Obviously you'll need to ensure you know the endianness and size of what is in your `NSData`.

e.g.

```
#include <CFByteOrder.h>

// Bytes to uint32_t
NSData *data = <THE_DATA>;
void *bytes = [data bytes];
uint32_t *intBytes = (NSInteger*)bytes;
uint32_t swapped = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(*intBytes); ///< If the data in `data' is big endian

// uint32_t to bytes
uint32_t someInt = 1234;
uint32_t swappedInt = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(someInt); ///< If we want to store in big endian
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&swappedInt length:sizeof(swappedInt)];
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want the CFSwapInt32* family of functions.

See [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: This takes care of the endianness part of my question, but I am still looking for some code that will go from bytes to data and the reverse.

Comment: OK, well, that part of the question wasn't there before. The other answer addresses that piece.