# Changing the endianness of audio data being passed to OpenAL

Tags: objective-c, c, endianness, openal

I am using OpenAL in the iOS app that I'm working on and our client gave us a bunch of audio files that are all in big-endian format. My problem is that OpenAL only plays little-endian formats.

So I figure all I need to do is find the audio data, and reverse it, correct?

My code for extracting the audio data (taken from the OpenAL tutorial):

```
-(void)addSound:(NSString*)theSound
{
// get the full path of the file
NSString* fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:theSound ofType:@"caf"];
// first, open the file
NSLog(@"fileNAme is ===== %@", fileName);
AudioFileID fileID = [self openAudioFile:fileName];

// find out how big the actual audio data is
UInt32 fileSize = [self audioFileSize:fileID];

// this is where the audio data will live for the moment
unsigned char * outData = malloc(fileSize);

// this where we actually get the bytes from the file and put them
// into the data buffer
OSStatus result = noErr;
result = AudioFileReadBytes(fileID, false, 0, &fileSize, outData);
NSLog(@"OUT DATA IS == %d", outData);
AudioFileClose(fileID); //close the file

if (result != 0) NSLog(@"cannot load effect: %@",fileName);

NSUInteger bufferID;
// grab a buffer ID from openAL
alGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);

// jam the audio data into the new buffer
alBufferData(bufferID,AL_FORMAT_STEREO16,outData,fileSize,44100);

// save the buffer so I can release it later
[bufferStorageArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:bufferID]];

NSUInteger sourceID;

// grab a source ID from openAL
alGenSources(1, &sourceID);

// attach the buffer to the source
alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);
// set some basic source prefs
alSourcef(sourceID, AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
alSourcef(sourceID, AL_GAIN, 1.0f);

//alSourcei(sourceID, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);

// store this for future use
[soundDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:sourceID] forKey:theSound];

// clean up the buffer
if (outData)
{
    free(outData);
    outData = NULL;
}
}
```

I figure `unsigned char * outdata;`
is what I need to reverse (after the audio file data is loaded into it, of course), but I have no idea how to do so. Can anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert big endian to little endian when reading from a binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823921/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-when-reading-from-a-binary-file)

Comment: see concise solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552864/bit-conversion-tool-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, you should use `ExtAudioFileRead` after configuring the `ExtAudioFile`'s `AudioConvertor`'s format. it will save you a lot of time. you might swap yourself if you know all your input files have the same sample format.

`ExtAudioFile` is in AudioToolbox.framework on OS X and iOS (basically a layer above `AudioFile` with more high level capabilities), and you can create one by wrapping an `AudioFile`.

`AudioConvertor` could also be used without `ExtAudioFile`.

in some cases, you can just use the OS X `afonvert` utility to swap them to LE, and be done with it without adding (unnecessary) programming challenges.

writing your own endian-swapping routines for arrays isn't hard - it's just time consuming, tedious, and you typically need to make sure it's *fast* and capable of supporting unnaturally aligned sample data. this involves:

```
for (each sample) {
  reverse order of bytes in sample
}
```

W'rkncacnter furnished this link: [Convert big endian to little endian when reading from a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823921/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-when-reading-from-a-binary-file)

you can use that approach it if is naturally aligned. and you would need variants for each size and sample description you would see on input. the OS also offers `OSSwap` routines, but these don't handle all sample formats -- they focus on builtin types.

Comment: thanks for the response. ill try that out. I would prefer to use afconvert, but unfortunately for this app the user will be able to download additional media to it so it must be done programmatically.

Comment: @rbertsch8 ok, bummer - i also provided an overview of how you would approach writing your own swapping routines.

Comment: Here's an implementation that loads any format iOS supports into 16-bit PCM LEI (OpenAL): https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/OALAudioFile.m  If possible, you should try to get the client to use AAC encoding, saving up to 10x the bandwidth compared to uncompressed audio.

Comment: @Karl thanks. this is an implementation using `ExtAudioFileRead`