# Convert little endian to big endian including 0 (zero)

Tags: hex, endianness

Im trying to convert little endian to big endian and having trouble.
I have an array that has 2 bytes of unsigned char which is hex values.
and i would like to make it big endian by the zeros are gone and i cant get the values i want.

For example, 
My goal is to get

```
array[0] = 0b
array[1] = 40
output = 0b40 so i can see this value as 2880 when %d
```

so i used

```
output = (array[1]>>4) | (array[0]<<4);
```

but in reality, i see

```
printf("output = %x04\n", output);
output = 00b4
```

I want that output to be 0b40 so i can get 2880 when i do

```
printf("output = %x\n", output);
output = 0b40

printf("output = %d\n", output);
output = 2880
```

thanks guys any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the bottom up by eight bits, not four, and not shift the top:

```
output = (array[0]<<8) | array[1];
```

See [convert big endian to little endian in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func) for more discussion and code.