# Converting bytes to uint32 in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I'm continuously sending arrays of pixel values (uint32) from LabVIEW to a C-program through TCP/IP. I'm using the recv function in Ws2_32.lib to receive the bytes, but I have to convert them back to uint32 data type and doesn't really know how to do it in this case. I'll be thankful if anyone shows how to do it.

Thanks in advance

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 256

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s , new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    int c;
    typedef unsigned char bytes[256];
    typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
    int iResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;




    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 13000 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    do {    
        iResult = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("%d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

        } 
    while( iResult > 0 );

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you do not show/describe how you send the data, advices on how to receive it are just guesses.

Comment: I'm sending the data as 2d arrays of uint32 integers. I'm first sending the string length as 4 bytes (I32 typecast to a string.)  Then sending the string after flattening from a 2-D array of uint32.

Comment: You'd better show to code.

Comment: It is written in LabVIEW and I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ensure that your `do while` block works as expected.

Concerning you question

As we know one dimensional array can be think as pointer to memory block.
so

```
char *ar = recvbuf ;

char x1= *ar; //will get first byte (index 0)
char x2=*(ar+1); //will get second byte (index 1)
```

Also as array and pointer in our case can be used  interchangeable
We can access as indexed way too

```
   char x1=ar[0];// the same as *ar
    char x2=ar[1]; //= *(ar+1);
```

As you see char will move one byte, but in our case we want to move 4 bytes. so we will 
make our pointer to point to int.

```
   int *intarr=(int *) recvbuf ; //recvbuf is address
```

now we can access and fetch ints using the same syntax

```
    int x1=*intarr;
    int x2= *(intarr+1); //  *((int*)(ar+4))
//or
    int x1=intarr[0];
```

And note that if `inarr` point to for example to address `00004` , `(inarr+1)` will point to
`00004+ 4=00008th` address. Cause pointer arithmetic will know that next int address will be obtained using `addr+sizeof(int)`.

Next issue. Bytes order can be different. see [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigendian)
On that case we have to make conversion. either we will write our functions. or we can use
`htonl ntohl` . Or see this manual conversion [endiannes conversion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func)

Then coming to my code: `uint32_t *endp=(uint32_t*)(recvbuf+iResult);` will point to end of our array. so we will increment our pointer until it be equal to endp; `while(p<endp) ++p;` and simple we will use `*` dereference operator to get that value. after `++p p` will point to next int block,and fetching `uint32_t` from that address will be equal to `*p`. And we will increment that until `endp`

Another option just to use index syntax. so we have to first calculate length of our array. How many ints we got in our array .this will be equal `iResult/sizeof(uint32_t)` `iResult our length in bytes`. After that we can access index using `*(p+index)` or more nice way `p[index]`

```
  ...

uint32_t *p=(uint32_t*)recvbuf;
uint32_t *endp=(uint32_t*)(recvbuf+iResult);



//here is accessing
while(p<endp){
    //ntohl(*p) if it was send from begin endian
    uint32_t value=*p;p++;
}

//or
uint32_t *p=(uint32_t*)recvbuf;
size_t len=iResult/sizeof(uint32_t);
//
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
   uint32_t value= p[i]; //and again if there is endian problem solve it using ntonl htonl

}
```

Comment: @user2292615 see if it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t char byteArray[4] = {0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFA, 0xCE};
    uint32_t int32Word = *(uint32_t *)byteArray;

    printf("%#X\n", int32Word);

#ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN
    int32Word = ((int32Word & 0xFF000000) >> 24) | 
                ((int32Word & 0x00FF0000) >> 8)  | 
                ((int32Word & 0x0000FF00) << 8)  | 
                ((int32Word & 0x000000FF) << 24);

    printf("%#X\n", int32Word);
#endif

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output (My Machine is Little Endian):

> 0xCEFAEFBE
>   0xBEEFFACE
>   Press any key to continue . . .

If you capture 4 `uint8_t`s at a time from the stream, you can convert them to an `uint32_t`.  Note that if your platform is little endian, you will have to do some byte rearranging.