# Analog le64toh in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, endianness

I need find analog of function le64toh in windows. I find that functions htond.htonf,htonl,htonll,htons are similar, but they converst network byte order to something, but function le64toh do the oposite thing, as far as i understand.

Comment: Maybe writing own function.

Comment: I think about this too, can you tell me some hint to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func