# How to convert little-endian 64 to host byte order in C++

Tags: c++, endianness

I need to convert little-endian 64 to host byte order. In winapi i can't find such functions, so i need to write my own, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Considering that you mention "winapi" I guess you're on a Windows system, which means that unless you're on a **very** old system (we're talking 1990's when Windows NT was ported to some big-endian machines) chances are that you're on a x86/x86_64 system, which already is little-endian. So converting little-endian to little-endian is a no-op.

Comment: A quick search on google returns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func as the top result - it has some answers you might find useful.

Answer (score 3):

Use [htonll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj710199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It converts an unsigned `__int64` to network byte order.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not a portable function, it's Windows only.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - yes, but the questioner mentions the Windows API in his question, so it seems reasonable.

Comment: This converts host order to network byte order which is big endian. 

The OP asked for converting little endian to host order.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to get the host's endiannes first and you can decide after that if you need to convert anything:

```
#define BIG_ENDIAN 1
#define LITTLE_ENDIAN 0

int getEndiannes()
{
   int n = 1;
   char *p = &n;
   if(*p) 
       return LITTLE_ENDIAN; 
   else
       return BIG_ENDIAN ;  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you can use `uint64_t htobe64(uint64_t host_64bits);`

Check the [`man` page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/htobe64/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading external data, the usual solution is to build
up the individual values as specified:

```
unsigned long long      //  The only type guaranteed long enough for 64 bits
readData( std::istream& source )
{
    unsigned long long results = source.get();
    results |= source.get() <<  8;
    results |= source.get() << 16;
    results |= source.get() << 24;
    results |= source.get() << 32;
    results |= source.get() << 40;
    results |= source.get() << 48;
    results |= source.get() << 56;
    return results;
}
```

Of course, you really need some sort of error checking, in case
the file ends in the middle of the 8 bytes.  (But it is
sufficient to check once, after all of the bytes have been
read.)

If the data is already in a buffer, then just substitute
`static_cast<unsigned char>(*p++)` for `source.get()` (where `p`
points to the position in the buffer).  In this case, you also
have to ensure that there are 8 bytes between the initial `p`
and the end of the buffer *before* doing the conversion.