# Converting Bytes to signed short and int value to bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have int values of two bytes for example `254 = 0xFE, 112 = 0x70`. 
I need to convert them to signed short. Now the signed short value should be -400.

And then after changing that value I have an integer for example `-410` that i need to convert back to two bytes.

How could i achieve that for iOS?

Comment: objective-c is not c++ and c++ is not objective-c. You need to specify which language you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bytes are in the native architecture [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), then it's as simple as

```
uint8_t *p = someAddress;
short value = *(short *)p;

value = 410;
*(short *)p = value;
```

However if the bytes are in a foreign endianness you are required to convert each byte of the integer, which is slow.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func) is one, of many, examples.