# Writing number as raw binary to file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite

So I'm trying to write the value of a `long` as raw binary to a file with `fwrite()`, here's a test file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* stream;
    stream = fopen("write", "wb");
    long number = 0xfff;
    fwrite(&number, sizeof(long), 1, stream);
}
```

When opening the written file in a text editor, this is the output:

```
ff0f 0000 0000 0000
```

while I was expecting something like `0000 0000 0000 0fff`.

How do I write the desired result correctly as raw binary?

Comment: Search for "marshalling"/"serialisation". There is enough to be found on here and the rest of the web about that. Use shifts/masking to serialise data, not just write the memory area.

Comment: [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)...dark magic

Comment: It probably has more to do with how hex dumps is displayed by whatever you are using to display them.

Comment: This is how little-endian works. Least-significant byte first.

Comment: if you always want to write in a consistent way you'll need to convert byte order first using `htonl` which will always use the same **output** byte order, you'll need to convert back after loading with `ntohl` to get your machine's native byte order.

Comment: Welcome to the Big Endian camp! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem. You're seeing it as `ff0f 0000 0000 0000`  cause of the endian of the machine!
Try using `fread()` instead!

Answer (score 3):

Read about [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which states how a bytes are arranged in a word (or double/quad word, et cetera) in a computer system.

I'm assuming you've coded and compiled this example on a X86 system, which is *little-endian*, so, the least significant bits COME FIRST. The opposite of that arrangement is called *big-endian*.

Now, it is clear that your objective in this exercise is to **marshall** (or **pickle**, depending on how your prefer your jargon) some bytes to be later retrieved, possibly by another program.

If you develop a program that uses fread() and and reads the data in the same way (using sizeof(long) so you don't read too much data) and **in a machine with the same endianness**, it will magically work, and the number you expect is gonna be back. But, if you compile and run the "read" tool in a machine with the opposite endianness, reading the same input file, your number will be garbled.

If your objective is to marshall data, you should be better off with a tool to help you marshall your bytes in a way that is **endianness-agnostic**, that is, a library that helps you get the data in the correct order. There are libraries out there that take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

as other have pointed out in the comments, this is an endianness "issue". That it, it is only an issue if you are going to run your software on systems with an other endianness.

[This very useful resource](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/) is the first result for the "c endian" google search, at least for me. I hope it helps you.

---

Edit: I will dig a bit more into the details below.

To determine what is the endianness of the machine you are currently running on, write a known value (for example, `0xAABBCCDD`) into memory, then take a pointer to that value and cast it to a char* or other 1-byte data type. Read the same value again, byte by byte, and compare the ordering with what you wrote. If they are the same, you are on a big endian machine. If not... Then you could be on a little (more probable) or middle (less probable) endian machine. You can in either case generate a "swap map" for reordering the bytes; which is the reason why I chose four different byte values in the above example.

But, how to swap those values? An easy way, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002), is to use bit shifts with masks. You can also use tables and swap their values around.