# Swapping bytes of unsigned short integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, endianness

I have a partially working function which involves writing to a file.

I have an array, `arr`, of type `unsigned short int` and each element must be written to a file in binary format.

My inital solution was:

```
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    fwrite(&arr[i], 1, sizeof(unsigned short int), source);
}
```

The code above works when writing `unsigned short ints` to the file. Also, `source` is a pointer to the file which is being written to in binary format.  However, I need to swap the bytes, and am having trouble doing so. Essentially, what is written to the file as `abcd` should be `cdab`.

My attempt:

```
unsigned short int toWrite;
unsigned short int swapped;
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    toWrite = &arr[i];
    swapped = (toWrite >> 8) | (toWrite << 8);

    fwrite(swapped, 1, sizeof(unsigned short int), source);
}
```

However I get a segmentation fault core dump as a result. I read and used the upvoted answer to this question - [convert big endian to little endian in C [without using provided func]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func) - but it doesnt seem to be working.  Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `fwrite(&swapped, 1 , sizeof(unsigned short int) , source);` fwrite needs an address. compiler has probably warned you. read the warnings. also `toWrite = arr[i];` or you swap the address...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your attempt is very wrong (and the answers you copied from are okay, the problem isn't in the swapping itself)

First you're taking the *address* of the value to swap, then you're passing the *value* instead of the address to write. It should be:

```
unsigned short int toWrite;
unsigned short int swapped;
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        toWrite = arr[i];
        swapped = (toWrite >>8) | (toWrite <<8); // that part is OK
        fwrite(&swapped, 1 , sizeof(unsigned short int) , source);  
}
```

I'm positive that the compiler warned you for this. Warnings are useful.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of non portable binary formats.

Swapping the numbers is a hack that is error prone because it makes the program non portable: whether to swap the values or not depends on the endianness of the system where you compile and run the program. Your program has a very simple bug: you pass the value of `swapped` instead of its address. You can fix it with:

```
fwrite(&swapped, sizeof(swapped), 1, source);
```

Yet a better solution for your problem is to handle endianness explicitly in your program. This is a portable solution to write the numbers in big endian order:

```
/* writing 16 bit unsigned integers in big endian order */
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    putc(arr[i] >> 8, source);
    putc(arr[i] & 255, source);
}
```

This is the alternative version if you are expected to write in little endian order:

```
/* writing 16 bit unsigned integers in little endian order */
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    putc(arr[i] & 255, source);
    putc(arr[i] >> 8, source);
}
```

Note that it is somewhat confusing to name the stream variable for an output file `source`.