# How do I write the 4 bytes of an int32_t to a binary file in big-endian order in C?

Tags: c, endianness

I want to write the 4 bytes of an `int32_t` to a binary file in big-endian order. I used `fwrite()` directly with a pointer to my `int32_t`, and it somewhat works, but the problem is that my integer is written in little-endian order, with the smallest bytes written first. For example, if I write:

```c
int32_t specialInt = 262;
fwrite(&specialInt, 4, 1, myFile);
```

and I open it with my hex editor, I see:

```
06 01 00 00 ...
```

which is backwards compared to how I want it. I would like:

```
00 00 01 06 ...
```

How should I get my `int_32t` to be in big-endian order? Is there a built-in C library function that will get the bytes in the correct order, or should I use `memcpy()` to put the bytes into a temp char array, then write the bytes one by one backwards into the file?

Comment: Assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8` ... `unsigned char value[4]; value[0] = (unsigned)specialInt >> 24; value[1] = (unsigned)specialInt >> 16; value[2] = (unsigned)specialInt >> 8; value[3] = (unsigned)specialInt;` and `fwrite(value, 4, 1, myFile);`

Comment: There will be numerous duplicates of this question on the site already. Basically you need to shift the individual bytes in place. There's also the `htons` etc non-standard functions for the benefit of PC programmers who are scared of trivial bitwise operators :)

Comment: @pmg: `unsigned` is not guaranteed to be wide enough for `int32_t`.

Comment: And all of that doesn't help with the difference between 2s-complement and sign+magnitude encoding.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: `int32_t` is two’s complement. `int` may be one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude, but `int32_t` may not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Where in the standard does it say `int32_t` is two's complement? It's just an alias to one of the core integer types, which may or may not be two's complement.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: C 2018 7.20.1.1 1 says “The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width *N*, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation…” The standard does not say it is an alias to one of the core integer types.

Comment: @EricPostpischil wow, learn something new every day. Didn't know the intN_t must be two's complement. Must be fun for integer promotion if you have a hypothetical CPU with sign+magnitude ints and intN_t type. As for the aliased part: C 2018 7.20.1.1 3 says: *it shall define the corresponding typedef names*

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, note, a compliant C compiler need not implement `intN_t` on non-2's complement machines.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Yes, `int32_t` is a `typedef` name, but it is not necessarily a `typedef` name for one of the core integer types. A C implementation could define types `int`, `__intTwosComplement`, and `__intSignAndMagnitude`, and others, and then it could make `int32_t` an alias for `__intTwosComplement`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert big endian to little endian in C \[without using provided func\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks pmg for writing the answer in the comment:

Assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`:

```c
unsigned char value[4];
value[0] = (uint32_t)specialInt >> 24;
value[1] = (uint32_t)specialInt >> 16;
value[2] = (uint32_t)specialInt >> 8;
value[3] = (uint32_t)specialInt;
fwrite(value, 4, 1, myFile);
```

Comment: Just FYI: this works irrespective of the endianness of the computer.

Comment: As a bonus it also works without various 3rd party muppet libraries that takes ten times longer to find/get working than it takes to write down this simple, readable code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `htonl()` function from POSIX 2001 standard available in `arpa/inet.h` header. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl

Big endian is Internet byte order, known as "network byte order".

You need to transform `int32_t` to `uint32_t`. This cast is defined by C standard. Next transform it to network endian via `htonl()` and then write it to a file:

```
int32_t specialInt = 262;
uint32_t encodedInt = htonl((uint32_t) specialInt);
_Static_assert(sizeof encodedInt == 4, "Oops");
fwrite(&encodedInt, 4, 1, myFile);
```

It could be abbreviated a bit with a compound literal.

```
fwrite(&(uint32_t) { htonl((uint32_t)specialInt) }, 4, 1, myFile);
```

Comment: `htonl()` exists in Windows too — include _either_ `<winsock_2.h>` _or_ `<windows.h>` (or if including both do it in that order) — then `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32")`. If you are compiling with GCC or Clang you’ll have to link with `-lws2_32`.

Comment: You don't need to check if `uint32_t` is 4 bytes, just check that `CHAR_BIT` is 8 bits. That is, if you insist on portability to wildly exotic DSPs or fictional computers - otherwise just drop the assert.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, I know about it. Those machines a quite rare though still in use. A new C standard should make CHAR_BIT equal to 8 mandatory. Make "de facto" standard ... a standard.