# Does boost have portable way to use ntohl/htonl/ntohs/htons type functions?

Tags: c++, boost, udp

I am using UDP in particular boost::asio::ip::udp::socket sockets if that helps?

What is the header file?

What headers/classes do I need to handle network byte ordering with the UDP under boost?

Comment: [This ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c/107099#107099) looks like a Boost solution.

Comment: What isn't portable about htons et al already?

Comment: @Steve-o. Thanks for pointing that out. I am aware the implementation is portable. However, I can not find a portable header. I have to include different headers for windows and for *nix as an example. So I  have do modify the code depending on platforms. I will probably create a header and put preprocessor directives to include headers depending on platforms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found it is enough to `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` as this pulls in all the platform dependent headers and gives access to `htonl/ntohl` which is exactly what I need.

Thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_short
in boost/asio/detail/socket_ops.hpp

Comment: is there also a function in boost for swapping int64 or double?

Answer (score 2):

POSIX.1-2001 standard is `<sys/types.h>` & `<netinet/in.h>`, on Windows you have 2 stacks to choose from `<winsock2.h>` or `<ws2tcpip.h>` & `<winsock2.h>`, the latter is now the preferred choice as it supports Unicode naming but note that they are incompatible.

Platforms pre-2001 might require other headers such as `<arpa/inet.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738556(VS.85).aspx

For *nix:

> http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/htonl.htm

A quick search did not provide anything resonable in boost.
Hopefuuly somebody else will find somthing.