# C++ 32-bit word byte swapping

Tags: c++, byte, swap, endianness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c)

I was wondering how you would byte swap a 32-bit word

I have a huge buffer of these words and each of them need to be byte swapping due to endianness.

Answer (score 6):

Either use the functions provided by your OS (cf. Martin Beckett's answer), or alternatively, if you are looking for a way to do this out of interest you may be interested in the following code snippet:

```
x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8 | (x & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8;
```

Comment: Yeah, to complete the byte swapping a second line is needed: `x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8 | (x & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8;`

Comment: @bames53 Yes, you're right! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Use [htonl / ntohl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  provided by your OS

Comment: That will only swap bytes if the native format is the reverse of network format.

Comment: @MikeSeymour true, but it's most likely that this is what the user needs. Anyone writing some low level non-network order driver is likely to know how to do it anyway. This seemed a good 99% answer

Comment: Well actually I am writing a low level non-network order driver... For an internship though so its above my head. I understand the concept but I am used to high level languages.