# Reading data from Dukascopy tick binary file

Tags: c++

I have downloaded the Dukascopy tick data and I have decompressing it with easylzma library. The original compressed binary file is EURUSD/2010/00/08/12h_ticks.bi5 (EURUSD/2010/ian/8/12h) After decompressing we get the following format:

```
+-------------------------+--------+-------+
|           time          |  Bid   |   Ask |
+-------------------------+--------+-------+
000003CA 00022EC0 00022EB6 40CCCCCD 41180000
000004F5 00022EB6 00022EB1 4099999A 404CCCCD
```

(You can download original compressed file from:
[EURUSD/2010/00/08/**12h_ticks.bi5**](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0PJ51qZTKX2QXJhdGRKNE9uRWs).
After decompressing it with lzma we get the file: 
[**12h_ticks**](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0PJ51qZTKX2eDd0MmM5R2NyR00))

Reading the binary file:

```
int ii1;
int ii2;
int ii3;
float ff1;
float ff2;
ifstream in("12h_ticks",ofstream::binary);
in.read((char*)(&ii1), sizeof(int));
in.read((char*)(&ii2), sizeof(int));
in.read((char*)(&ii3), sizeof(int));
in.read((char*)(&ff1), sizeof(float));
in.read((char*)(&ff2), sizeof(float));
std::cout << " ii1=" << ii1 << std::endl;
std::cout << " ii2=" << ii2 << std::endl;
std::cout << " ii3=" << ii3 << std::endl;
std::cout << " ff1=" << ff1 << std::endl;
std::cout << " ff2=" << ff2 << std::endl;
in.close();
```

I get the following result:

```
ii1=-905773056
ii2=-1070726656
ii3=-1238498816
ff1=-4.29492e+08
ff2=8.70066e-42
```

What is wrong? I can't read data from binary file. Please help me.

Comment: Just curious, How did you figure out file format ?

Answer (score 9):

The data appears to be stored in big endian format in the file.  You'll need to convert it to little endian when you load it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void ByteSwap(T* p)
{
    for (int i = 0;  i < sizeof(T)/2;  ++i)
        std::swap( ((char *)p)[i], ((char *)p)[sizeof(T)-1-i] );
}

int main()
{
    int ii1;
    int ii2;
    int ii3;
    float ff1;
    float ff2;
    std::ifstream in("12h_ticks",std::ofstream::binary);
    in.read((char*)(&ii1), sizeof(int));
    in.read((char*)(&ii2), sizeof(int));
    in.read((char*)(&ii3), sizeof(int));
    in.read((char*)(&ff1), sizeof(float));
    in.read((char*)(&ff2), sizeof(float));

    ByteSwap(&ii1);
    ByteSwap(&ii2);
    ByteSwap(&ii3);
    ByteSwap(&ff1);
    ByteSwap(&ff2);

    std::cout << " ii1=" << ii1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ii2=" << ii2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ii3=" << ii3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ff1=" << ff1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ff2=" << ff2 << std::endl;
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the result:

```
ii1=970
ii2=143040
ii3=143030
ff1=6.4
ff2=9.5
```

I grabbed the ByteSwap function from here if you want to read more about that subject.  [How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c)

Comment: is this dataformat still valid? incase if you happen to know.

Comment: if I understood it correctly it reads first 16 bits represents time, next 16 bits ask, next 16 bid, next 32 bits ask vol, next 32 bits bid volume, is that correct ?

Comment: I don't know anything about what the values in the file represent, I just recognized an endian issue.

Comment: when I decompress 18k file it turned into 3.5G. There is something definitely wrong

Comment: I got the decompression done with http://macpkg.sourceforge.net/. Can you tell me number of bytes you are reading for int and for float  here. if I read it by 2 for int and 4 for float I don't get proper decoded data back

Comment: Both are 4 bytes long.

Comment: cool. I got Java one working. out of curiosity how did you reverse engineer file format ?

Comment: I didn't, I've just seen a lot of byte swapping issues.  The code in the question worked, it just needed the endian swap.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious how the OP was able to reverse engineer format. it is pretty cool

Answer (score 5):

ii1 is seconds within this hour

ii2 is Ask * 10000

ii3 is Bid * 10000

ff1 is Ask Volume

ff2 is Bid Volume

Comment: ii1 seems to be milliseconds within.

Comment: out of curiosity how did you reverse engineer file format ?