# Reading Dukascopy data files

Tags: matlab, file-io

I read the answers to [Reading data from Dukascopy tick binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035808/reading-data-from-dukascopy-tick-binary-file), but I'm having trouble doing it in Matlab. I essentially want the same answers from the source file.

So far, I have:

```
fid=fopen(filename);
ii1=fread(fid,8,uint8,'b'); 
ii2=fread(fid,1,uint8,'b');
ii3=fread(fid,8,uint8,'b');
ff1=fread(fid,8,uint8,'b');
ff2=fread(fid,8,uint8,'b');
```

I'm having difficulty getting the right results, that is:

```
ii1=970
ii2=143040
ii3=143030
ff1=6.4
ff2=9.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. Assumming that the results you suggest are the correct ones, you need to do this:

```
fid = fopen('12h_ticks');
ii1 = fread(fid,1,'int32','b');   % int32 or uint32
ii2 = fread(fid,1,'int32','b');   % int32 or uint32
ii3 = fread(fid,1,'int32','b');   % int32 or uint32
ff1 = fread(fid,1,'float32','b'); % single precision
ff2 = fread(fid,1,'float32','b'); % single precision
fclose(fid);                      % Don't forget to close the file
```

The outputs are all converted to double precision values by `fread`. If you want to keep the data in its native format you can do this instead for the relevant lines:

```
ii1 = fread(fid,1,'int32=>int32','b');
ii2 = fread(fid,1,'int32=>int32','b');
ii3 = fread(fid,1,'int32=>int32','b');
ff1 = fread(fid,1,'float32=>single','b');
ff2 = fread(fid,1,'float32=>single','b');
```

Finally, since this is Matlab, you might want to read in the data as two vectors:

```
ii = fread(fid,3,'int32','b');   % 3-by-1 vector
ff = fread(fid,2,'float32','b'); % 2-by-1 vector
```