# Reading SQLite header

Tags: c, file-io, sqlite, endianness

I was trying to parse the header from an SQLite database file, using this (fragment of the actual) code:

```
struct Header_info {
    char *filename;
    char *sql_string;
    uint16_t page_size;
};

int read_header(FILE *db, struct Header_info *header)
{
    assert(db);
    uint8_t sql_buf[100] = {0};

    /* load the header */
    if(fread(sql_buf, 100, 1, db) != 1) {
        return ERR_SIZE;
    }

    /* copy the string */
    header->sql_string = strdup((char *)sql_buf);

    /* verify that we have a proper header */
    if(strcmp(header->sql_string, "SQLite format 3") != 0) {
        return ERR_NOT_HEADER;
    }

    memcpy(&header->page_size, (sql_buf + 16), 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the relevant bytes of the file I'm testing it on:

```
0000000: 5351 4c69 7465 2066 6f72 6d61 7420 3300  SQLite format 3.
0000010: 1000 0101 0040 2020 0000 c698 0000 1a8e  .....@  ........
```

Following [this](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) spec, the code looks correct to me.

Later I print `header->page_size` with this line:

```
printf("\tPage size: %"PRIu16"\n", header->page_size);
```

But that line prints out 16, instead of the expected 4096. Why? I'm almost certain it's some basic thing that I've just overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an endianness problem. x86 is little-endian, that is, in memory, the least significant byte is stored first. When you load `10 00` into memory on a little-endian architecture, you therefore get `00 10` in human-readable form, which is `16` instead of `4096`.

Your problem is therefore that `memcpy` is not an appropriate tool to read the value.

See the following section of the  [SQLite file format spec](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) :

> 1.2.2 Page Size
>
> The two-byte value beginning at offset 16 determines the page size of
>   the database. For SQLite versions 3.7.0.1 and earlier, this value is
>   **interpreted as a big-endian integer** and must be a power of two between
>   512 and 32768, inclusive. Beginning with SQLite version 3.7.1, a page
>   size of 65536 bytes is supported. The value 65536 will not fit in a
>   two-byte integer, so to specify a 65536-byte page size, the value is
>   at offset 16 is 0x00 0x01. This value can be interpreted as a
>   big-endian 1 and thought of is as a magic number to represent the
>   65536 page size. Or one can view the two-byte field as a little endian
>   number and say that it represents the page size divided by 256. These
>   two interpretations of the page-size field are equivalent.

Comment: Then what should I use to convert the values to big-endian format?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c) is tagged C++ but has answers suitable to C as well. Also remember to treat the special case mentioned in the spec (`00 01` for 65536) and be extra careful if your code might run on big endian machines at some point (in that case you wouldn't want to swap bytes).

Answer (score 2):

It seems an endianness issue. If you are on a little-endian machine this line:

```
memcpy(&header->page_size, (sql_buf + 16), 2);
```

copies the two bytes `10 00` into an `uint16_t` which will have the low-order byte at the lower address.

You can do this instead:

```
header->page_size = sql_buf[17] | (sql_buf[16] << 8);
```

**Update**

For the record, note that the solution I propose will work regardless of the endianness of the machine (see this [Rob Pike's Article](http://commandcenter.blogspot.fr/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html)).