# Struct to u_char conversion

Tags: c++, struct, unsigned-char

Let's say I have some structs similar to this:

```
struct a {
    uint8_t v1[6];
    uint16_t type;
    uint8_t v2[6];
    uint32_t something_long;
};

struct b {
    uint8_t v3;
    uint8_t v4;
};

struct c{
    a a;
    b b;
}
```

and I fill data like (is this correct?):

```
int main() {...

    c my_struct;

    my_struct.a.v1[0] = 0x01;
    my_struct.a.v1[1] = 0x02;
    .
    .
    .

    my_struct.a.type = 2048; // <- does this integer convert to "hex"?
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is get `my_struct` and be able to make `u_char buff` from `my_struct`

```
u_char buff[sizeOf(c)]; 

someConversionStuffHere(c, buff);
//function returns data like:
    //buff[0] = 0x01; //wanted result
    //buff[1] = 0x02; //wanted result
```

**so I can take `buff` and use it in 3rd party library that requires u_char as parameter.**

I've tried some crazy things like:

looping in while and using `sscanf()`, I mean I can print out `c` in hex using:

```
u_char *string_ptr = (U_char *)&p;
int i = sizeof(c);

while(i--) {
    u_char c = *string_ptr++;
    printf(" %x ", (u_char) c);
}
```

This prints "correctly" values `uint8_t v1[6]` and `uint8_t v2[6]`, but when I try to print out 2048 as hex (it should be `0x800`) it prints out `0 8` instead (not `08 00` as I would expect).

I would love debug this but C/C++ isn't PHP where I can primitively print out anything without problem.

Comment: You are looking for "endian-conversion" or "endianness". It would appear your system is using "little endian", so the bigger part is later than the smaller part of values that are more than a single byte.

Comment: 2048 does not fit in a `uint8_t`, it needs two bytes. In order to do a re-interpretation of multiple bytes as a single number, you need to know the "sub-structure" of the buffer.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use pcap_dump(). `Data contained in each section will always be saved according to the characteristics (little endian / big endian) of the dumping machine.`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for comment I looked it up in here http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html . I did mistake I am trying to add integer value 2040 to different value I made an edit.
What about the other part "saving" struct as u_char ?

Comment: `my_struct.b.type = 2048;` - there is no member `type` in `b`; only `v3` and `v4`.

Comment: You could just write `(uchar *)&my_struct`. Whether or not this does what you want, depends on this mystery function you are calling.

Comment: @MattMcNabb thank you that was the solution. Yes it was a typo (b.type), and I think I solved my problem but another popped up, because of (in real code) my struct `a` has length (`sizeof(a)`) 14 and 15th and 16th position is padded with "nothing" - 0xcc and that is not good, any suggestions?

Comment: You could insert "dummy" members in your struct so that you can refer to this padding directly. Or you could tell your compiler to not use padding, but that is less portable.

Comment: "less portable" what exactly that means? If someone else wants to compile he/she might not be able to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what @Mats said is correct: this is because of **endianness**..  You can see an illustration of what's going on "under the covers" on the Wikipedia page: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian

Comment: Thank you for comment I solved endians with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/105339/1564365