# Endianness when dereferencing a uint32_t pointer to raw data

Tags: c++, endianness

I have an `uint32_t*` pointer `charData` set to data that is stored in LE order.
When I simply dereference the pointer and store it in a `uint32_t` it is interpreted falsely (i.e. as Big Endian).
What's the best way to rotate the bytes in c++?

```
unsigned char arr[4] = {0x02, 0x11, 0x01, 0x6B };
unsigned char* charData = arr;
uint32_t value = *((uint32_t*) charData);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that's what I meant by falsely.

Comment: Possible anser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c

Comment: Code like this is used a lot but it's actually undefined behaviour. `*((uint32_t*) charData)` should be a `memcpy`.

Comment: Just do: `uint32_t value = (((*charData) & 0xFF) << 24) | (((*charData) & 0xFF00) << 8) | (((*charData) & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((*charData) >> 24);`, better is encapsulated in a method (ex: ChangeEndianess).

Comment: @WhozCraig i took the array as an example. I have no influcence on th actual source for the data.