# C++: How to swap byte order of a wchar_t

Tags: c++, unicode

I want to convert the endianness of an UTF-16 character array stored as `wchar_t*`. Assuming `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` in this case.

Converting from BE to LE and LE to BE are both needed so ntoh/nton doesn't work.

I've read [How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c) but I'm not sure how to apply it to a `wchar_t`.

Is there a way to swap the 2 bytes of a `wchar_t`? Or do I have to convert it to binary first?

EDIT: Though I didn't test all answers, I believe they all works. That said, I think Jarod42's answer is more straightforward.

Comment: You know `wchar_t` is 4 bytes and the encoding is UTF-32?

Comment: @Deduplicator: On Windows `wchar_t` is typically 2 bytes and UTF-16

Comment: @BillyONeal, yes I was going to post that. There is the C++ standard and then what MS actually does. I had gathered Ockham may have left off visual-c++ as a tag.

Comment: @Michael: The C and C++ standards make the size of `wchar_t` implementation defined; so there's nothing standards-related here.

Comment: @Deduplicator: There's nothing stopping a Unix implementation where `wchar_t` is 2 bytes. Considering the question says "assuming `wchar_t` is 2 bytes" I think the question is more than fine.

Comment: @BillyONeal In my comment I should have made it clear that I was referring to how MS implemented it per the standards. G++ has compiler flags to define the size of a wchar_t as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following may help:

```
std::uint16_t swap_endian(std::uint16_t u)
{
    return (u >> 8) | ((u & 0xFF) << 8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the bytes of any type, no matter how long:

```
template<class T> void reverse_bytes(T& x) {
    char* a = std::addressof(x);
    for(char* b = a + sizeof x - 1; a<b; ++a, --b)
        std::swap(*a, *b); 
}
```

Comment: For any type which don't overload `operator &` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks for the nit, it's gone now.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this should work:**

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t c = L'A';

    // char* can alias anything
    char* cptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c);

    if(sizeof(wchar_t) == 2)
        std::swap(cptr[0], cptr[1]);
    else if(sizeof(wchar_t) == 4)
    {
        std::swap(cptr[0], cptr[3]);
        std::swap(cptr[1], cptr[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Converting from BE to LE and LE to BE are both needed so ntoh/nton doesn't work.

I still propose to use ntoh/hton functions family:
BE == network byte order
LE == host byte order

so:
For BE -> LE use: uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
For LE -> BE use: uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);

Comment: BE/LE stand for Big/Little endian, and host is not necessary LE.