# How to properly read data from memory (memcpy)

Tags: c++, c, memory, bit-shift

I have some tables, for example one declared as `uint8_t keyLock[16];`, and I have saved contents of these tables in the flash memory of my MCU.  In this memory its looks like below:

```
Address    Data
00190008 - BA98B694
0019000C - E854B6E7
00190010 - 9200B2C9
00190014 - 42F8B048
```

When I copy the flash data into my table via the `memcpy` function (`memcpy(keyLock, 0x00190008, 32);`) the contents of table end up as if initialized this way:

```c
keyLock = {
    0xBA, 0x98, 0xB6, 0x94, 0xE8, 0x54, 0xB6, 0xE7,
    0x92, 0x00, 0xB2, 0xC9, 0x42, 0xF8, 0xB0, 0x48
}
```

I want the contents to be as if the table were initialized like this:

```
keyLock = {
    0x94, 0xB6, 0x98, 0xBA, 0xE7, 0xB6, 0x54, 0xE8,
    0xC9, 0xB2, 0x00, 0x92, 0x48, 0xB0, 0xF8, 0x42
}
```

What is wrong with my `memcpy()` call, and how should I write it to fill the table with the desired content, as above?

Comment: memcpy does byte-for-byte copy.  Most likely you are writing flash byte-swapped.

Comment: Endianness strikes again.

Comment: It 's the [Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the world as we know it. And I feel fine.

Comment: @eof again strikes Endianness.

Comment: @user4581301  I think you mean "fine feel I and"

Comment: Try a for loop that copy byte by byte, and try another loop that copies uint32  by uint32, and compare results.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c) answer for more information about endianness

Comment: @Yakk: oN. s'iI "niaga sekirts ssennaidnE"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you store 4 bytes of memory as a 32 but integer whose value is `BA98B694`, which byte goes first?

In your question, you implicitly assume the `BA` byte goes first, but on your system it appears that `94` goes first.

Your `memcpy` is doing everything right.  Your problem is your expectation of endianness, or the layout of your table in flash.

You can fix it by simply swapping the order of each 4 byte dword.

```
void endian_4byte_swap( uint32_t* bytes ){
  std::swap(bytes[0],bytes[3]);
  std::swap(bytes[1],bytes[2]);
}
void endian_fix_table( uint32_t (&table)[16] ){
  for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
    endian_4byte_swap(&table[4*i]);
}
```

But that fixes the symptom rather than the disease.  The real fix is to fix the table in flash, assuming you have control over it.

Comment: In `gcc` there is a header `<byteswap.h>` that defines `bswap16()`, `bswap32()` and `bswap64()`.