# "Junk" displayed when displaying array of characters

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stack

I'm trying to convert an address to its equivalent in Little-Endians using the following code :

```
void AddressToLittleEndian(UINT32* adr, UINT32 value) { *adr = value; }


int main()
{
    char *ptr = (char*) 0x41424344;
    char Adr[4];
    AddressToLittleEndian((UINT32*)Adr, (UINT32)ptr);
    cout << Adr;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It works without error but gives me the following result :

> DCBA╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠DCBA╠╠╠╠<,ö∩╨≈Å

The desired result is `DCBA` and I can somehow substring the first 4 character but actually I'm curious to know why this happens? It seems the junk code comes from the stack but I wonder what's wrong with this code that causes the stack leak ?

Comment: You char array is not a '\0' terminated string. Why should it print like one?

Comment: You didn't convert here, you just use local endianess.

Comment: I tried counting UBs, but I miss a few fingers. You cannot cast pointers to integer types. You'll find help in the `htoxxx()` function manuals.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c

Comment: What's the use case for changing the endianness of a pointer? You can't exactly send it to a different computer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an operator which takes a char array and sends it to `cout`. So `Adr` decays to a pointer to char which, when displayed, requires a zero value as the last character. A zero character can just be `0` or `'\0'`. It symbolises the end of string.

Change the code to:

```
char Adr[5];
AddressToLittleEndian((UINT32*)Adr, (UINT32)ptr);
Adr[4] = 0;
cout << Adr;
```

That should not display the "junk".