# Convert and mask bits of little endian to big endian

Tags: c++, qt, bit-manipulation, endianness

I am working on a Qt/C++ application. I want to show state of 3 hall sensors so I read it from  micro-controller this way:

```
uint8_t state = getState(whichMotor);
int numChars = sprintf(sBuff, "%d", state);
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3, sBuff, numChars);
```

State can be any 1, 5, 4, 6, 2 or 3.

Then in my Qt application I have 3 labels and want to show if corresponding bit is set in the number I receive from UART. I am sure I get the correct number, when I show it as integer its fine. But to break it down into 3 bits into three labels I fail as it just shows 1 1 1 or 0 0 0.

Here is my code on PC:

```
const void MotorWidget::setHallState(const QString& s)
{
 int hallState = s.toInt();
 ui->lbValueHallC->setText(hallState & 0b100 > 0 ? "1" : "0");
 ui->lbValueHallB->setText(hallState & 0b010 > 0 ? "1" : "0");
 ui->lbValueHallA->setText(hallState & 0b001 > 0 ? "1" : "0");
}
```

For example, if I receive `hallState` as 5, label C should show "1", label B should show "0" and label A should show "1"...but as I said I only get 111 or 000 regardless of what I receive.

I suspect this might be big-endian little-endian thing...but I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: As an aside: your API should be `setHallState(int)` or even `setHallState(HallState)`, where `HallState` is an enum or enum class.

Comment: @KubaOber well for me it is easier to just receive ascii characters from the micro-controller...but I know what you mean...thanks/

Comment: ASCII characters aren't a `QString`!!! They are `QByteArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add some parentheses:

```
const void MotorWidget::setHallState(const QString& s)
{
 int hallState = s.toInt();
 ui->lbValueHallC->setText((hallState & 0b100) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
 ui->lbValueHallB->setText((hallState & 0b010) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
 ui->lbValueHallA->setText((hallState & 0b001) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
}
```

Also have a look here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

If you can I suggest you to use `Boost C++` libraries: in [this link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html) you can find all you need.

If you're using **GCC** you can use the `int32_t __builtin_bswap32 (int32_t x)`

Alternative you can write you own function... it's quite easy, at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c)

Comment: I don't want to use a huge library just for something simple really