# How can i reverse the order of hex in c++

Tags: c++

To start with, I have a `char array` that store data

```
unsigned char dat[3];

memset(dat, 0, sizeof(dat));                    
memcpy(dat, &no, 2);
```

when I inspect dat, it contain a hex of 0xfd 0x01 
as the value of no is 509, the hex should be 0x01 0xfd

I'm wondering should I be concern of the order of the hexadecimal,
should I change the order. Many thanks

Comment: [LE vs BE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: Just swap the endianess

Comment: @user1095108 they don't know what that means and why its happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is little endian. It's hardware dependent and on little endian platform first byte is the least significant one  when treated as part of multi-byte value. Look up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Essentially if CPU is little endian, then value `0x12345689` would be represented as set of bytes starting with 0x89. On big endian it's opposite order and on mixed endian it may change during run-time.

Answer (score 1):

The question really is what do you want to do next ? On your current hardware (Little Endian) this is how the system orders bytes of a numeric. The least significant byte comes first: 0xfd 0x01.

In case you really want to swap this byte order, for whatever reason, checkout: [How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c)