# How to convert unsigned long long to float/int in C?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, long-integer, unsigned-long-long-int

An unsigned long long variable has the value of  "`40 36 70 A3 D7 0A 3D 71`" in hex. If I print it with the `%f`conversion specifier I get the right conversion from IEEE-754. How can I cast this variable to a floating one or `int`, even if I lose some decimals?

I have tried casting it but it gives me bad values. Example here:

```
unsigned long long hex = 0x403670A3D70A3D71;
float cast_float = (float)hex;
```

Comment: You cannot successfully convert it to `int` because it is out of range of `int`, but you can convert it to an approximate `float` value with `(float)myull`. But I don't understand what you mean by "If I print it as %f I get the right conversion from IEEE-754" so please **show the actual code** you are using.

Comment: Did you mean `double`? That is the same size as `unsigned long long` but `float` is not.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "If I print it as %f"?  The likely -- but undefined(!) -- behavior of passing your variable `hex` to `printf` as the argument corresponding to a `%f` directive is completely different from the behavior to be expected from converting that variable's value to `float` or `double` via a cast.  Do you mean to work on the variable's *value* or on its *representation*?

Comment: Don't you need `UL` on the end of the literal?

Comment: "I have tried casting it but it gives me bad values." --> what was the bad value?  What was expected?

Comment: @stark `UL` suffix would not make a difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `unsigned long long` variable contains a value that is a valid `double` value, then you could use *type punning*, for example using unions:

```
union
{
    unsigned long long i;
    double             f;
} value = { .i = 0x403670A3D70A3D71 };

printf("0x%llx is %f\n", value.i, value.f);
```

Note that this is valid *only* if the value in the integer have the same bit-pattern as a valid double-precision floating point value on your system. Otherwise it could lead to *undefined behavior*.

---

Now if you want to convert it to the `int` value `22` (as `0x403670A3D70A3D71` is the binary representation of the `double` value `22.44`), then you first need to use type-punning to get the floating point value, then use the [`floor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor) function to truncate it to an integer value (but still in floating point type), and lastly cast that to an `int`:

```
int int_val = (int) floor(value.f);
```

Comment: Good answer but you missed the `int` part of the question until yet.

Comment: What value did you see with `floor()`?  Why not `int int_val = (int) value.f;`?

Comment: I know that this is a correct answer concerning C (moreover the OP asked about C) but I think it is interesting to add that using union like that in C++ has undefined behavior. Might be interesting for future readers as I shot myself in the foot previously. See [Undefined Behavior in C++: Type Punning](https://adriann.github.io/undefined_behavior.html).